# How to set custom auth claims through Firebase and identify platform

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am following the firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#setting_custom_and_session_claims) to set custom auth claims for users logging into my app for the first time using firebase auth + identify platform but it does not seem to be working.

When a user logs in for the first time, I want them to get the `admin` custom claim. I have created the following blocking function and have verified from the logs that it runs when I log in for the first time to my app using sign-in with google:

```
exports.beforeCreate = functions.auth.user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {
  return {
    customClaims: {
      admin: true,
    },
  };
});
```

I would expect this to create the admin custom claim in the user's token. However, when I get a list of claims using another cloud function the admin claim does not appear.

```
exports.getclaims = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const uid = req.query.uid as string;
  if (uid) {
    const user = await admin.auth().getUser(uid);
    res.send(user.customClaims);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

If I set the claim using the admin SDK directly using the below cloud function, the admin claim does appear.

```
exports.setclaim = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const uid = req.query.uid as string;
  if (uid) {
    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true});
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong in the beforeCreate function?

Comment: FYI I've tested your code in my own test environment and I have the same behaviour: The claim is not set. All packages were updated before tests. I would suggest you contact the Firebase support.

Comment: Same behaviour. Have you found an answer @treesandgreens?

Comment: It seems to be a bug. There is some discussion on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73535561/firebase-beforecreate-not-adding-custom-claims)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open GitHub issue regarding that. See [sessionClaims content not getting added to the decoded token](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1135). Also, there's a [fix](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pull/1199) that has been recently merged regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the snippet you provided, there does not appear to be anything wrong with beforeCreate as coded.

You may want to check you do not have a beforeSignIn that is overwriting the customClaims directly or via sessionClaims.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#modifying_a_user

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `onCreate` method instead of `beforeCreate` how it is shown on the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#logic)

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    try {
      // Set custom user claims on this newly created user.
      await getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {admin: true});

      // Update real-time database to notify client to force refresh.
      const metadataRef = getDatabase().ref('metadata/' + user.uid);

      // Set the refresh time to the current UTC timestamp.
      // This will be captured on the client to force a token refresh.
      await  metadataRef.set({refreshTime: new Date().getTime()});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

The main point here is that you need to create the user at first and then update claims and make the force update of the token at the client side:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
```